# Is it permitted to cook the calf in the milk of it's mother?

Tags: halal-haram, food

It has been said that Muslim dietary laws are largely based on the Jewish ones. SO does Islam permit the calf to be cooked in his mother's milk or is that also prohibited just like in Judaism?

Comment: Halal is similar to Kosher guidelines but NOT identical to it. Hence, Islam permits the calf to be cooked in it's mother's milk

Comment: That sounds like an answer AHmed, could you post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect to assume that every dietary prohibition in Judaism is going to be applicable in Islam as well, rather it is established that Islamic dietary laws are more relaxed:

> #### ويحل لهم الطيبات ويحرم عليهم الخبائث ويضع عنهم إصرهم والأغلال التي كانت عليهم
>
> Makes lawful for them the good things and prohibits for them the evil and relieves them of their burden and the shackles which were upon them.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:157](http://quran.com/7/157)</sup>
>
> #### وعلى الذين هادوا حرمنا ما قصصنا عليك من قبل وما ظلمناهم ولكن كانوا أنفسهم يظلمون
>
> And to those who are Jews We have prohibited that which We related to you before. And We did not wrong them [thereby], but they were wronging themselves.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 16:118](http://quran.com/16/118)</sup>

The default rule about food is that it is halal unless there is evidence to contrary:

> #### هو الذي خلق لكم ما في الأرض جميعا
>
> It is He who created for you all of that which is on the earth.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:29](http://quran.com/2/29)</sup>

No prohibition on consumption of milk with meat exists within Islamic texts, so there is no reason for it to not be permitted.

Comment: I figured as much, seeing as you can eat buttered chicken at many halal restaurants.

Answer (score -1):

> It has been said that Muslim dietary laws are largely based on the Jewish ones. SO does Islam permit the calf to be cooked in his mother's milk or is that also prohibited just like in Judaism?

In Islam, animals being alive, are to be treated with consideration; to cook a calf in its mothers milk is reprehensible; and says a great deal of a human being who would do such a thing; although it is not explicitly denounced in the Qu'ran, I would consider it haram.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate about why this is immoral. I have not ever done this, you seem to feel strongly about it, I'm just wondering why you find this immoral?

Comment: @Neil Meyer: If you don't see why this immoral, I don't see how an argument is going to convince you.